# The set $ \bigcap_{1}^{\infty } \left ( -1-n^{-1},1+n^{-1} \right )$ is identical to $[-1,1]$?

Tags: set-theory

> The set $ \bigcap_{1}^{\infty } \left ( -1-n^{-1},1+n^{-1} \right )$
>   is identical to
>
> a)$[-1,1]$
>
> b)$(-1,1]$
>
> c)$[-1,1)$
>
> d)$(-1,1)$

The correct answer is (a)$[-1,1]$.

Can someone explain how we come to this conclusion?

We need to find the intersection of $ \left ( -2,2 \right ),\left ( -1.5,1.5\right ).... $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1$ and $-1$ (and every number between) are in every interval. So they are in their intersection.